# Use multiple versions of jQuery in one page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have got generated scripts and I'm not able to delete them in "head" and now I have got problem because one of my script using JQuery 1.7 but website can see only JQuery 1.8

**head:**

```
<script src="/Modules/Orchard.jQuery/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Themes/MS/scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do you know what I have to do? to tell website: "for this script use JQuery 1.7"

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Comment: Have you considered to make your script compatible for jQuery 1.8? There's a not-so-huge change between 1.7 and 1.8

Comment: Modules in Orchard are very big :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: hope this helps

Use `.noconflict()`
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page